# Spring MVC @PathVariable annotation

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web

I am struggling with one of the spring annotaions, that is @PathVariable. I look forward to find help in you guys..

My goal is to get the url to look like this "../product/1" instead of "../product?productId=1", but my main problem is that I would like to input id number in text box and then submit it with a button. Example: If I type 1 in the textbox I would like to receive page with element of id 1 from my database.

**All of this while I am in my cart page.**

My code

JSP File

```
        <form:form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="product" method="get">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"  placeholder="Search" name="productId"/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form:form>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/cart")
    public String showCart() {
    return "cart";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProductById(@PathVariable(value = "productId") int productId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("product", productService.findProductById(productId));
        return "product";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the button type to `button` and write a javascript function as `submitForm`

```
<form:form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="product" method="get">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"  placeholder="Search" name="productId" id="productId"/>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm()">Search</button>
            </form:form>
```

to send the product id in ajax request as below

```
function submitForm(){
   var prodId = document.getElementById("productId").value;   
   $.ajax({
       url : '/product/'+prodId;
       ... 
  })
}
```